# How can I reduce this repetition? (Java)

Tags: java

So, there's this "do while" statement in one of my codes, and as you can see I keep repeating the if statement in it. How can I reduce it?
I'm new to this, and I just can't thik of a better way to solving this problem.

```
    do {
        if (id1 <= 15) {
            np++;
        }if(id2<=15){
            np++;}
        if(id3<=15){
            np++;}  
        if(id4<=15){
            np++;}  
        if(id5<=15){
            np++;}  
        if(id6<=15){
            np++;}
        if(id7<=15){
            np++;}
        if(id8<=15){
            np++;}
        if ((id1>=16)&&(id1<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id2>=16)&&(id2<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id3>=16)&&(id3<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id4>=16)&&(id4<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id5>=16)&&(id5<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id6>=16)&&(id6<=30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id7>16)&&(id7<30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id8>16)&&(id8<30)){
            np2++;}
        if ((id1 >= 31)&&(id1<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id2 >= 31)&&(id2<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id3 >= 31)&&(id3<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id4 >= 31)&&(id4<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id5 >= 31)&&(id5<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id6 >= 31)&&(id6<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id7 >= 31)&&(id7<=45)){
            np3++;}
        if ((id8>=31)&&(id8<=45)){
            np3++;}  
        if ((id1>=46)&&(id1<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if ((id2>=46)&&(id2<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if ((id3>=46)&&(id3<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if ((id4>=46)&&(id4<=60)){
            np4++; }
        if ((id5>=46)&&(id5<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if ((id6>=46)&&(id6<=60)){
            np4++; }
        if ((id7>=46)&&(id7<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if ((id8>=46)&&(id8<=60)){
            np4++;}
        if (id1>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id2>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id3>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id4>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id5>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id6>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id7>60){
            np5++;}
        if (id8>60){
            np5++;}
    p=np+np2+np3+np4+np5;
    }while(p==0);   

}}
```

Comment: What are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Please look up some java containers as the variable names and the many conditions do not look like a programming solution but more like an additional problem caused by not using "the right words" in the language (java here). What often helps us help beginners to not only make code shorter but also to have an idea what the task to be implemented is, as sometimes solutions are not about going a step further in the wrong direction ...

Comment: @Dilettant I like that "going a step further in the wrong direction", so I quoted you in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37663261/5221149). :-)

Comment: As mentioned, look into renaming some of those variables; that makes it REALLY hard to read that code.  Also, my suggestion is to find all of the conditions that increment np1 and group them; then find all of the conditions that increment np2 and group them, then np3, etc...

Comment: @Kalmino Code has already grouped all the conditions that increment `np` (there is no `np1`). All 8 `if` statements are there, right next to each other.

Comment: @Andreas I mean group them into a single condition joined with and/or instead of having 8 conditions that increment np and then 8 more that increment np2.  It doesn't change a ton but it will reduce the number of lines.  I have a hard time reading this solution because of all the repetition but that's likely just a personal quirk.

Comment: @Kalmino It *does* change a ton, because current code may increment `np` 8 times, while changing to and/or would only increment once even if multiple conditions are true. --- OP probably also has a hard time reading this code, which is the point of the question: How you improve it *without* changing the result.

Comment: @Andreas Oh snap, in my head I looked at it as a giant if/else block but you're 100% correct those are all separate conditions. Holy crap. That's terrible.

Comment: @Kalmino Hence my shorter [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37663261/5221149) to clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to reduce that code is to turn the 8 individual `id` variables into an array of 8. Something like this:

```
int[] ids = new int[8];
// code to assign ids here
int np = 0, np2 = 0, np3 = 0, np4 = 0, np5 = 0;
do {
    for (int id : ids)
        if (id <= 15)
            np++;
        else if (id <= 30)
            np2++;
        else if (id <= 45)
            np3++;
        else if (id <= 60)
            np4++;
        else
            np5++;
} while (np + np2 + np3 + np4 + np5 == 0);
```

Of course the code doesn't sense, because each iteration of the inner loop will increment one of the `np` variables, so each iteration of the outer loop will increment the sum of them by 8, meaning that sum can never be `0` at the end of the first iteration of the outer loop.

Hopefully, your code is a reduction of something else, so that it makes sense to you. Otherwise, the [comment by Dilettant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662916#comment62804383_37662916) is right: This answer is helping you "go a step further in the wrong direction". If you describe the real problem, we might be able to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: nps can be initilized with negative values...well its an assumption which I feel from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 8 `ids` in an array. Then loop over the `ids` performing the same few `if` statements on them during each iteration.

That or use some sort of data structure to hold all these `id` and `np` variables, which would clean up your code dramatically.